# Explicit file list in csproj

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I would like to prevent MS Build from picking up `.cs` files from my project directory automatically. Instead, I only want explicitly included files to be compiled:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

...

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="./Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I configure MS Build to work this way?

```bash
$ dotnet --version
7.0.400
```

Comment: Seems like a very odd requirement, the new csproj format is designed to stop this from being necessary. Have you tried excluding all cs files with a wildcard? e.g. `<Compile Remove="*.cs" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [EnableDefaultCompileItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enabledefaultcompileitems) property to false:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will disable the feature to automatically include cs files in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#use-wildcards-to-specify-items) for [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#BKMK_RemoveAttribute) attribute for `Compile`. Something like the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="**/*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first excluding all .cs files, and then including the ones you need. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="**/*.cs" />
  <Compile Include="./Program.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that the `**` is a wildcard to allow searching all directories. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#use-wildcards-to-specify-items) for more.